# How to change axis as a variable

Tags: plotting

I run the example：

```
Clear["Global`*"]
F = x^2/(a^2 + x^2);
ParametricPlot[{a x, F}, {a, 0, 4}]
```

But failed.
My object is replace (a) as (a*x), then use ParametricPlot (or others).
Is there anything I can do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me

```
F[x_][a_] := x^2/(a^2 + x^2)
H[x_][a_] := a x
ParametricPlot[{H[x][a], F[x][a]}, {x, 0, 2}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

and it produces

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome. If this solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it